# An integral leads to complementary error functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, special-functions, error-function

I am reading a paper Albrecher, Constantinescu and Loisel "2011Explicit ruin formulas for models with dependence among risks" and getting stuck at one integral (Example 2.4): 
$$\int _{\frac{\lambda }{c}}^{\infty }\frac{\lambda }{\theta  c}e^{-u \theta } e^{\frac{\lambda  c}{ u}} \frac{\alpha }{2\sqrt{\pi
 \theta ^3}}e^{-\frac{\alpha ^2}{4\theta }}d\theta.$$
The $\theta^{-\frac{5}{2}}$ in the integrand kills my attempts. Three authors claim that it should be:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lambda }{\alpha ^2 c}e^{-\frac{\alpha ^2c}{4\lambda }}\left\{-\frac{2 \alpha }{\sqrt{\pi \frac{\lambda }{c}}}+e^{\frac{\left(\alpha
 c-2 \lambda \sqrt{u}\right)^2}{4c \lambda }}\left(1+\alpha \sqrt{u}\right)\text{erfc}\left[\sqrt{\frac{u \lambda }{c}}-\frac{\alpha }{2\sqrt{\frac{\lambda
}{c}}}\right]+e^{\frac{\left(\alpha  c+2 \lambda \sqrt{u}\right)^2}{4c \lambda }}\left(-1+\alpha \sqrt{u}\right)\text{erfc}\left[\sqrt{\frac{u \lambda
}{c}}+\frac{\alpha }{2\sqrt{\frac{\lambda }{c}}}\right]\right\},
\end{equation}
where $\operatorname{erfc}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_t^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$.

I cannot see how to do this. I start from the above and end with the following:
$$\frac{\lambda }{\alpha  c}\left\{-\frac{2 }{\sqrt{\pi \frac{\lambda }{c}}}e^{-\frac{\alpha ^2c}{4\lambda }}+\frac{ e^{\frac{u \lambda }{ c }}}{\sqrt{\pi
}}\int _{\frac{\lambda }{c}}^{\infty }e^{-u \theta -\frac{\alpha ^2}{4\theta }}\text{  }\left(\frac{1}{\theta \sqrt{\theta }}+\frac{2u}{\sqrt{\theta
}}\right)d\theta \right\}.$$ 
I cannot see why this is the first equation too. Any helps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you would want to simplify your problem a bit because not many MSE users will be interested after seeing the messy and huge expressions.

Comment: There is a typo, the formula with $\operatorname{erfc}$ is the correct value for
$$\int_{\lambda/c}^\infty
 \frac \lambda {\theta c} e^{-u \theta} e^{\lambda u/c}
 \frac \alpha {2 \sqrt{\pi \theta^3}} e^{-\alpha^2/(4 \theta)} d\theta$$
($e^{\lambda u/c}$ instead of $e^{\lambda c/u}$). For a given $k$, a closed form for $\int \theta^{k + 1/2} e^{-a \theta - b/\theta} d\theta$ exists because
$$\int e^{-(a x + b/x)^2} dx =
\frac {\sqrt \pi} {4 a} \left(
 e^{-4 a b} \operatorname{erfc} \left( \frac b x - a x \right) -
 \operatorname{erfc} \left( \frac b x + a x \right) \right).$$

Comment: Yes，I just realise this typo. Many thanks for this.

Comment: This solution looks very similar, but I'm not sure if it helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3051321/441161